# How to get all value from List inside List in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3

I have List of Cards... Evey card have some `name, description, price` but Also have another list inside called `services`. I am trying to get List `services` into output of `font-awesome-icon` so I could store icons and just past them for function `v-for`.

```
Cards: [{
    name: "Dvoulůžkový pokoj",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do " +
        "eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur " +
        "adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.",
    price: "2500",
    services: [{
        icon: "1"
    }, {
        icon: "2"
    }, {
        icon: "3"
    }, {
        icon: "4"
    }]
}]
```

So far I am able to get whole list of `services` and show output like this: 
`[ { "icon": "1" }, { "icon": "2" }, { "icon": "3" }, { "icon": "4" } ]`

```
<p v-for="services in Cards" :key="services">{{ services.services }}</p>
```

How can I get these values one by one and render them?

Next part is about changing values of `icon` from "1,2,3,4" into `fas.faPhone` which should get icon from FontAwesome library. After this I need to get this icon into the code down below:

```
<div v-for="icon in Cards" :key="icon">
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="icon.services" />
</div>
```

So it would display icons one by one. How can I do that? Is there any other or more effective way how to do it?

**EDIT 1:**
I have been able to render first icon from the List of `services` by:

```
<div v-for="(icons, index) in Cards" :key="index">
  <font-awesome-icon :icon="icons.services.values().next().value.icon" />
</div>
```

How can I render every value of the List not just first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just add a nested `v-for`

```
<div v-for="(card, index) in Cards" :key="`card-${index}`">
   <template v-for="(icon, icon_idx) in card.services">
      <font-awesome-icon :icon="icon.icon" :key="`icon-${icon_idx}`" />
   </template>
</div>
```